# How do I get rid of a Dimensional Door?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-hexxit

I was playing survival with the Hexxit mod pack online, and I made a rift door (from Dimensional Doors mod) with a rift blade.

Now I can't get rid of it, I have tried to remove it by spamming the rift remover but I can't get it to go.

So how do I remove a Dimensional Door?

Comment: Have you tried TNT?  Blowing stuff up is always a good solution.

Comment: @Batophobia: I guess you never played anything with the Thaumcraft 2 mod. Taint don't care 'bout TNT. ;)

Answer (score 4):

To use the rift remover, you must expose a rift first. You do this by breaking your dimensional door with a pickaxe or axe and then using the remover on the particles that are created in its place.

Answer (score 0):

If you throw an item through the portal, it will close, however a black cloud will remain. In order to get rid of the cloud you must get a rift closer and right click the cloud. This will completely remove the portal.

Answer (score -1):

just throw an item through it and it will close

Comment: Culd you expand a bit on that ? Can you provide any sources ?